# Send Output errors of nohup to syslog

Tags: bash, nohup, rsyslog

I'm attempting to write a bash script that uses nohup and passes errors to rsyslog.

I've tried this command with different variations of the log variable (see below) but can't get the output passed to anything but a std txt file. I can't get it to pipe.

```
nohup imageprocessor.sh > "$LOG" &
```

Is it possible to pipe nohup output or do I need a different command.

A couple of variations of log that I have tried

```
LOG="|/usr/bin/logger -t workspaceworker -p LOCAL5.info &2"
```

or

```
LOG="|logtosyslog.sh"
```

or

```
LOG="logtosyslog.sh"
```

Answer (score 8):

A way in `bash` to redirect output to syslog is:

```
exec > >(logger -t myscript)
```

`stdout` is then sent to `logger` command

```
exec 2> >(logger -t myscript)
```

for `stderr`

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. nohup will detach the child process, so piping the output of the nohup command isn't helpful. This is what you want:

```
nohup sh -c 'imageprocessor.sh | logger'
```