# embedded shell does not support redirection: exec 2> >(logger -t myscript)

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to run the command from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099885/send-output-errors-of-nohup-to-syslog):

```
exec 2> >(logger -t myscript)
```

It works great on my desktop linux system, however, on my embedded linux device the same command presents the following error:

```
-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

So I'm guessing my shell doesn't like part of the command syntax - most likely this portion:

`exec 2>`**>**`(logger -t myscript)`

In fact, while I understand that the `2>` is redirecting `stderr` I don't actually understand the syntax of the second `>` character in this case, is it another way of representing a pipe?

If I can understand what it is doing then perhaps I can modify my command to work with my limited shell on the embedded linux device.

Comment: That looks like an odd way to redirect. Can you edit your question to include specifically what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to learn more about the syntax in the command - I don't understand what it is doing

Comment: That's bash syntax. Be sure your shell is bash.

Comment: Like others have pointed out, this is a bash-specific. If you have to use a non-bash shell, `exec 2>&1 | logger -t myscript` might be an alternative. It doesn't do the exact same though: While your original code would only send stderr to the logger commands stdin, this would send both stdout and stderr to the logger commands stdin.

Comment: BTW, in the future, it'd be good practice to specify exactly _which_ embedded shell. I was only guessing, in my answer, that the one you were running would be POSIX-compliant (and am glad to hear that worked); some smaller builds of busybox include non-POSIX-compliant shells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax in question only works with bash (or other shells with ksh extensions). In the error

```
-sh: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

...you're trying to use that syntax with `/bin/sh`.

Be sure your script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, and that you invoke it with `bash yourscript` rather than `sh yourscript`.

---

A bit more explanation:

- `>(foo)` gets replaced with a filename (of the form `/dev/fd/##` if supported, or a named pipe otherwise) which receives output from a process named `foo`. *This is the part that requires bash or ksh extensions.*
- `exec <redirection>` applies a redirection to the current shell process (thus, `exec 2>stderr.log` redirects all stderr from the current command and its children to the file `stderr.log`).

Thus, `exec 2> >(foo)` modifies the stderr file descriptor (of your current shell session) to go to the stdin of command `foo`; in this case, `foo` is `logger -t myscript`, thus sending the process's stderr to syslog.

---

To perform the same operation on a more limited (but still POSIX-compliant) shell:

```
# note: if any security concerns exist, put the FIFO in a directory
#       created by mktemp -d rather than hardcoding its name

mkfifo /tmp/log.fifo                 # create the FIFO
logger -t myscript </tmp/log.fifo &  # start the reader in the background first!
exec 2>/tmp/log.fifo                 # then start writing
rm -f /tmp/log.fifo                  # safe to delete at this point
```

Answer (score 1):

`>( command )` is a bash construct called "process substitution". `man bash` says:

> Process  substitution  is  supported  on systems that support named pipes (FIFOs) or the `/dev/fd` method of naming open files.

Your shell doesn't seem to be bash, anyway.